# Anime/Cartoon about kids turning into dinosaur by beys

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

An anime or cartoon in which a group of 4 kids can turn into a dinosaur by battling with beyblade and one of them remains to support the remaining 3 in Another World.

It's been years since I watched the show so I don't remember much.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you see this?  Also, if it features Beyblades, doesn't it have to _be_ Beyblades, since they are a trademarked property?

Comment: Or do you just mean that they fight with something like spinning tops?

Answer (score 4):

Are you talking about ***[Dinofroz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinofroz)*** (2012-2015)?

> The series depicts the adventures of Tom Carter, a 12-year-old boy and his friends who, after playing a board game, are teleported to the past where they can transform into dinosaurs using stones called Rockfroz. It was foretold in legends that the dinofroz would come to save the people dinosaurs and world from the merciless rule of the dragons. The Shaman is a magician with immense magical powers who is a major help to the dinofroz in their journey to destroy the lord of dragons Neceron in retaining the rockfroz. The rockfroz is a unique rock fragment giving the dinofroz special powers in fighting the cruel generals of Neceron and their subordinate dragons. Another important help for the dinofroz is a huge mammoth named Nelsten whose family was killed by Neceron in an arm to arm combat. Tom's father is another important person who travels ahead of the four friends in time in order to save Tom from the dragon lord's cruel wrath.

They do turn into dinosaurs by spinning the stones as a yoyos. You might have mistaken the spinning as bey.
Hopefully, this answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Might you be talking about *[Dinosaur King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinosaur_King)*?

> Max Taylor is the son of paleontologist Dr. Spike Taylor. After falling out of bed early one morning and witnessing a meteor fall from the sky, Max sets out with his friends Rex Owen and Zoe Drake into a forest where the meteor had crashed. They find stones with the symbols for lightning, wind, and grass on them and a card with a picture of a Triceratops on it. The Triceratops that is later named Chomp is accidentally activated when Max rubs the card on the stone. The D-Team meet their new enemies in the Alpha Gang consisting of Dr. Z, Ursula, Zander, Ed, Seth, Laura, Rod, Helga, and the Alpha Droids. The Alpha Gang plans to obtain the Dinosaur Cards that were lost when their time machine exploded and stranded them in the present. Rex activated a Carnotaurus card which was named Ace and Zoe activated a Parasaurolophus which was named Paris. The D-Team and Alpha Gang often clash for possession of dinosaurs that are activated when their cards are activated. In the finale, Seth turns on his comrades with his Black Tyrannosaurus which is ultimately defeated. Seth attempts to bring Chomp back to the past which fails and Seth is sent into the past alone. The D-Team surrender their dinosaurs to Rex's original parents, with many tears.

They summon the dinosaurs, rather than transform into them, using cards for the upgrade and summon, but to my eyes, the animation styles are similar, so I could see the confusion.

Comment: *DInoSquad* would be a closer match for "transform into the dinosaurs", but there's no proxy battles there.